# How to properly carry values with the WITH clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a very long Cypher query where I load records from a file and try to create nodes and relationships. Some of the values may not exist on the file so the creational of nodes and edges have to be conditional.

I have created the different parts of the query and used the WITH statement hoping to pass the reference to the nodes to the subsequent statements which need them to create the edges.

```
// Mandatory Nodes
MERGE (session:Session{sessionId:"_d6648bbf-f747-42e5-a9b0-adb2cb0aea66-F3AC584AA3E2969240F3E9B285F23C03"})
  ON CREATE SET session.ipAddress="207.54.58.254"
MERGE (user:User {UserId:"dfd75378-a6df-4101-aeb7-fc2f866a75cc"})
MERGE (environment:Environment{server:"qac-portal.qac.awsdev.acme.com", type:"MT"})
MERGE (browser:Browser{type:"Chrome"})
  ON CREATE SET browser.version="70"
MERGE (os:OS{name:"Win10"})
  ON CREATE SET os.version="Win10"
MERGE (device:Device{type:"10.0"})
MERGE (city:City{name:"Atlanta"})
MERGE (country:Country{name:"United States", code:"US"})
MERGE (geoLocation:GeoLocation{latitude:"33.8274", longitude:"-84.3244"})
MERGE (tenant:Tenant{TenantId:"TAMTA1AT2_AX1"})

// Edges between mandatory nodes. 
MERGE (session)-[:ASSIGNED_TO]->(user)
MERGE (session)-[:STARTED_AT]->(geoLocation)
MERGE (geoLocation)-[:COORDINATES_FOR]->(city)
MERGE (city)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(country)
MERGE (session)-[:CONNECTED_WITH]->(browser)
MERGE (browser)-[:RUNS_ON]->(device)
MERGE (browser)-[:SUPPORTS]->(os)
MERGE (os)-[:OPERATES]->(device)
MERGE (environment)-[:HOSTS]->(tenant)

WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant

// Optional nodes
CALL apoc.do.when(("TAMTA1AT2_AX1" <> ''),
"MERGE (company:Company{name:'TAMTA1AT2_AX1'})",
'', {})
YIELD value AS company

WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, company
CALL apoc.do.when(("" <> ''),
"MERGE (cloudSuite:CloudSuite{name:''})",
'', {})
YIELD value AS cloudSuite

WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, company, cloudSuite
CALL apoc.do.when(('sample-hr' <> ''),
"MERGE (application:Application{name:'sample-hr'})",
'', {})
YIELD value AS application

WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, company, cloudSuite, application
CALL apoc.do.when(('lid://acme.sample-hr.ng1' <> ''),
"MERGE (applicationInstance:ApplicationInstance{applicationId:'lid://acme.sample-hr.ng1'})",
'', {})
YIELD value AS applicationInstance

WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, company, cloudSuite, application, applicationInstance
CALL apoc.do.when(('sample-hr_form_Employee_LRCMyGoalsForm' <> ''),
"MERGE (screen:Screen{name:'sample-hr_form_Employee_LRCMyGoalsForm'})",
'', {})
YIELD value AS screen

WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, company, cloudSuite, application, applicationInstance, screen
CALL apoc.do.when(('sample-hr_form_Employee_LRCMyGoalsForm.ng1' <> '' ),
"MERGE (screenInstance:ScreenInstance{screenId:'sample-hr_form_Employee_LRCMyGoalsForm.ng1'})",
'', {})
YIELD value AS screenInstance

WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, company, cloudSuite, application, applicationInstance, screen, screenInstance
CALL apoc.do.when(((company IS NOT NULL) AND (tenant IS NOT NULL)),
'MERGE (company)-[r:OWNS]->(tenant)', '',{company:company, tenant:tenant}) YIELD value AS owns

// Edges between optional nodes
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant,
     company, cloudSuite, applicationInstance, application, screen, screenInstance
CALL apoc.do.when((("Accessed" = "Accessed") AND (screen IS NOT NULL) AND (screenInstance IS NOT NULL)),
'MERGE (screenInstance)-[r:INSTANCE_OF]->(screen)', '',{screen:screen, screenInstance:screenInstance}) YIELD value AS instanceOf

WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, company, cloudSuite, application, applicationInstance, screen, screenInstance
CALL apoc.do.when(((application IS NOT NULL) AND (applicationInstance IS NOT NULL)) AND ("Accessed" IN ["Accessed", "Launched", "Entered", "Exited"]),
'MERGE (application)-[r:DEPLOYS]->(applicationInstance)', '',{application:application, applicationInstance:applicationInstance}) YIELD value AS deploys

WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, company, cloudSuite, application, applicationInstance, screen, screenInstance
CALL apoc.do.when(((application IS NOT NULL) AND (cloudSuite IS NOT NULL)) AND ("Accessed" IN ["Accessed", "Launched", "Entered", "Exited"]),
'MERGE (application)-[r:BELONGS_TO]->(cloudSuite)' , '',{application:application, cloudSuite:cloudSuite}) YIELD value AS belongs_to

WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, company, cloudSuite, application, applicationInstance, screen, screenInstance
CALL apoc.do.when(((application IS NOT NULL) AND (browser IS NOT NULL)) AND ("Accessed" IN ["Accessed", "Launched", "Entered", "Exited"]),
'MERGE (application)-[r:COMPATIBLE_WITH]->(browser)', '',{application:application, browser:browser}) YIELD value AS compatible_with

WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, company, cloudSuite, application, applicationInstance, screen, screenInstance
CALL apoc.do.when((("Accessed" = "Accessed") AND (screenInstance IS NOT NULL) AND (applicationInstance IS NOT NULL)),
'MERGE (screenInstance)-[r:VIEWED_ON]->(applicationInstance)', '',{screenInstance:screenInstance, applicationInstance:applicationInstance}) YIELD value AS viewed_on

WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, company, cloudSuite, application, applicationInstance, screen, screenInstance
CALL apoc.do.when((("Accessed" = "Accessed") AND (application IS NOT NULL) AND (screen IS NOT NULL)),
'MERGE (application)-[:IMPLEMENTS]->(screen)', '',{application:application, screen:screen}) YIELD value AS implements

WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, company, cloudSuite, application, applicationInstance, screen, screenInstance
CALL apoc.do.when(((tenant IS NOT NULL) AND (application IS NOT NULL)),
'MERGE (tenant)-[r:PROVISIONED]->(application)', '',{tenant:tenant, application:application}) YIELD value AS provisioned

WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, company, cloudSuite, application, applicationInstance, screen, screenInstance
CALL apoc.do.case(
[ "Accessed" = "Logged In", "MERGE (session)-[:LOGGED_IN {start='2018-11-06 11:39:10'}]->(applicationInstance)",
  "Accessed" = "Logged Out", "MERGE (session)-[:LOGGED_OUT {end='2018-11-06 11:39:10'}]->(tenant)",
  "Accessed" = "Time Out", "MERGE (session)-[:TIMED_OUT {timeout='2018-11-06 11:39:10'}]->(tenant)",
  "Accessed" = "Accessed", 'MERGE (session)-[:ACCESSED]->(screenInstance)',
  "Accessed" = "Launched", 'MERGE (session)-[:LAUNCHED]->(applicationInstance)',
  "Accessed" = "Entered", 'MERGE (session)-[:ENTERED]->(applicationInstance)',
  "Accessed" = "Exited", 'MERGE (session)-[:EXITED]->(applicationInstance)' ],
'',
{applicationInstance:applicationInstance, screenInstance:screenInstance, session:session, tenant:tenant})
YIELD value AS action
RETURN *
```

When I run the query on the Neo4j Browser, it executes and gives me a result of: Added 10 labels, created 10 nodes, set 16 properties, created 9 relationships, completed after 8 ms. Which means that not all the nodes were created. It actually completes the first 2 sections: Mandatory Nodes and Edges, and stops right after creates the first node: "Company" in the optional Nodes section.  I don't have any clue on why would be stopping right at that point. My guess is that I am doing something wrong with the WITH clause there, which brings my next question. DO I have to use these many WITHs ?

Thank you in advance for any help.

### Edit 1

Thanks that fixed the problem with the Nodes part:

```
CALL apoc.do.when(('xxxForm.ng1' <> '' ),
"MERGE (screenInstance:ScreenInstance{screenId:'ljhgjhn-gjhhkjhkhr_form_Employee_LRCMyGoalsForm.ng1'}) RETURN screenInstance",
'', {})
YIELD value
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, value.application as application, value.company as company, value.cloudSuite as cloudSuite, value.applicationInstance as applicationInstance, value.screen as screen, value.screenInstance as screenInstance
```

I assumed that the same approach of using the values map would work with the edges part, but I am running into the same problem in there. Should I the values in the map still be available at that point?

```
CALL apoc.do.when(((company IS NOT NULL) AND (tenant IS NOT NULL)),
'MERGE (company)-[r:OWNS]->(tenant) RETURN company, tenant', '',{company:company, tenant:tenant}) YIELD value
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, value.application as application, value.company as company, value.cloudSuite as cloudSuite, value.applicationInstance as applicationInstance, value.screen as screen, value.screenInstance as screenInstance

CALL apoc.do.when((("Accessed" = "Accessed") AND (screen IS NOT NULL) AND (screenInstance IS NOT NULL)),
'MERGE (screenInstance)-[r:INSTANCE_OF]->(screen) RETURN screenInstance, screen', '',{screen:screen, screenInstance:screenInstance}) YIELD value
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, value.application as application, value.company as company, value.cloudSuite as cloudSuite, value.applicationInstance as applicationInstance, value.screen as screen, value.screenInstance as screenInstance
```

### Edit 2

```
MERGE (session:Session{sessionId:"_d6648bbf-f747-42e5-a9b0-adb2cb0aea66-F3AC584AA3E2969240F3E9B285F23C03"})
  ON CREATE SET session.ipAddress="207.54.58.254"
WITH session

MERGE (user:User {UserId:"dfd75378-a6df-4101-aeb7-fc2f866a75cc"})
WITH session, user

MERGE (environment:Environment{server:"xxx.yyy.zzz.com", type:"MT"})
WITH session, user, environment

MERGE (browser:Browser{type:"Chrome"})
  ON CREATE SET browser.version="70"
WITH session, user, environment, browser

MERGE (os:OS{name:"Win10"})
  ON CREATE SET os.version="Win10"
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os

MERGE (device:Device{type:"10.0"})
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device

MERGE (city:City{name:"Atlanta"})
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city

MERGE (country:Country{name:"United States", code:"US"})
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country

MERGE (geoLocation:GeoLocation{latitude:"33.8274", longitude:"-84.3244"})
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation

MERGE (tenant:Tenant{TenantId:"TAMTA1AT2_AX1"})
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant

MERGE (session)-[:ASSIGNED_TO]->(user)
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant

MERGE (session)-[:STARTED_AT]->(geoLocation)
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant

MERGE (geoLocation)-[:COORDINATES_FOR]->(city)
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant

MERGE (city)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(country)
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant

MERGE (session)-[:CONNECTED_WITH]->(browser)
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant

MERGE (browser)-[:RUNS_ON]->(device)
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant

MERGE (browser)-[:SUPPORTS]->(os)
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant

MERGE (os)-[:OPERATES]->(device)
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant

MERGE (environment)-[:HOSTS]->(tenant)
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant

// Creating Optional nodes.
CALL apoc.do.when(('sfgsfgn-ghr' <> ''),
"MERGE (application:Application{name:'afasdfn-ghr'}) RETURN application",
'', {})
YIELD value AS mapApplication
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, mapApplication.application as application

CALL apoc.do.when(("TAMTA1AT2_AX1" <> ''),
"MERGE (company:Company{name:'TAMTA1AT2_AX1'}) RETURN company",
'', {})
YIELD value AS mapCompany
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, application, mapCompany.company as company

CALL apoc.do.when(("" <> ''),
"MERGE (cloudSuite:CloudSuite{name:''}) RETURN cloudSuite",
'', {})
YIELD value AS mapCloudSuite
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, application, company, mapCloudSuite.cloudSuite as cloudSuite

CALL apoc.do.when(('lid://afasfafdsghr.ng1' <> ''),
"MERGE (applicationInstance:ApplicationInstance{applicationId:'lid://gfsgsr.ng1'}) RETURN applicationInstance",
'', {})
YIELD value
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, application, company, cloudSuite, value.applicationInstance as applicationInstance

CALL apoc.do.when(('lawson-ghr_form_Employee_LRCMyGoalsForm' <> ''),
"MERGE (screen:Screen{name:'lafsafsdfn-ghr_form_Employee_LRCMyGoalsForm'}) RETURN screen",
'', {})
YIELD value
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, application, company, cloudSuite, applicationInstance, value.screen as screen

CALL apoc.do.when(('sfgfsg-ghr_form_Employee_LRCMyGoalsForm.ng1' <> '' ),
"MERGE (screenInstance:ScreenInstance{screenId:'sgfdn-ghr_form_Employee_LRCMyGoalsForm.ng1'}) RETURN screenInstance",
'', {})
YIELD value
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, application, company, cloudSuite, applicationInstance, screen, value.screenInstance as screenInstance

// Creating Edges for optional nodes
CALL apoc.do.when(((company IS NOT NULL) AND (tenant IS NOT NULL)),
'WITH company, tenant MERGE (company)-[r:OWNS]->(tenant)', '',{company:company, tenant:tenant}) YIELD value as owns
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, application, company, cloudSuite, applicationInstance, screen, screenInstance

CALL apoc.do.when((("Accessed" = "Accessed") AND (screen IS NOT NULL) AND (screenInstance IS NOT NULL)),
'WITH screen, screenInstance MERGE (screenInstance)-[i:INSTANCE_OF]->(screen)', '',{screenInstance:screenInstance, screen:screen}) YIELD value AS instance_of
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, application, company, cloudSuite, applicationInstance, screen, screenInstance

CALL apoc.do.when(((application IS NOT NULL) AND (applicationInstance IS NOT NULL)) AND ("Accessed" IN ["Accessed", "Launched", "Entered", "Exited"]),
'WITH application, applicationInstance MERGE (application)-[d:DEPLOYS]->(applicationInstance)', '',{application:application, applicationInstance:applicationInstance}) YIELD value AS deploys
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, application, company, cloudSuite, applicationInstance, screen, screenInstance

CALL apoc.do.when(((application IS NOT NULL) AND (cloudSuite IS NOT NULL)) AND ("Accessed" IN ["Accessed", "Launched", "Entered", "Exited"]),
'WITH application, cloudSuite MERGE (application)-[b:BELONGS_TO]->(cloudSuite)' , '',{application:application, cloudSuite:cloudSuite}) YIELD value AS belongs_to
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, application, company, cloudSuite, applicationInstance, screen, screenInstance

CALL apoc.do.when(((application IS NOT NULL) AND (browser IS NOT NULL)) AND ("Accessed" IN ["Accessed", "Launched", "Entered", "Exited"]),
"WITH application, browser MERGE (application)-[c:COMPATIBLE_WITH]->(browser)", '',{application:application, browser:browser}) YIELD value AS compatible_with
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, application, company, cloudSuite, applicationInstance, screen, screenInstance

CALL apoc.do.when((("Accessed" = "Accessed") AND (applicationInstance IS NOT NULL)),
"WITH screenInstance, applicationInstance MERGE (screenInstance)-[v:VIEWED_ON]->(applicationInstance)", '',{screenInstance:screenInstance, applicationInstance:applicationInstance}) YIELD value AS viewed_on
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, application, company, cloudSuite, applicationInstance, screen, screenInstance

CALL apoc.do.when((("Accessed" = "Accessed") AND (application IS NOT NULL) ),
"WITH application, screen MERGE (application)-[i:IMPLEMENTS]->(screen)", '',{application:application, screen:screen}) YIELD value AS implements
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, application, company, cloudSuite, applicationInstance, screen, screenInstance

CALL apoc.do.when(((tenant IS NOT NULL) AND (application IS NOT NULL)),
'WITH tenant, application MERGE (tenant)-[r:PROVISIONED]->(application)', '',{tenant:tenant, application:application}) YIELD value AS provisioned
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, application, company, cloudSuite, applicationInstance, screen, screenInstance

CALL apoc.do.case(
[ "Accessed" = "Logged In", "MERGE (session)-[:LOGGED_IN {start='2018-11-06 11:39:10'}]->(applicationInstance)",
  "Accessed" = "Logged Out", "MERGE (session)-[:LOGGED_OUT {end='2018-11-06 11:39:10'}]->(tenant)",
  "Accessed" = "Time Out", "MERGE (session)-[:TIMED_OUT {timeout='2018-11-06 11:39:10'}]->(tenant)",
  "Accessed" = "Accessed", 'MERGE (session)-[:ACCESSED]->(screenInstance)',
  "Accessed" = "Launched", 'MERGE (session)-[:LAUNCHED]->(applicationInstance)',
  "Accessed" = "Entered", 'MERGE (session)-[:ENTERED]->(applicationInstance)',
  "Accessed" = "Exited", 'MERGE (session)-[:EXITED]->(applicationInstance)' ],
'',
{applicationInstance:applicationInstance, session:session, tenant:tenant})
YIELD value
RETURN *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the big issue here is a slight mistake in usage of the conditional procedures.

If you want to return anything in the conditional queries back out, you need to explicitly RETURN it in the query.

Also, the `value` that is returned is a map containing the values returned by the query, it isn't the value itself. It looks like you were assuming that when doing a MERGE for a single thing that the single variable was implicitly returned and that it was accessible via `value`, but that is incorrect. A correct usage would be something like this:

```
CALL apoc.do.when(("" <> ''),
"MERGE (cloudSuite:CloudSuite{name:''}) RETURN cloudSuite",
'', {})
YIELD value
WITH session, user, environment, browser, os, device, city, country, geoLocation, tenant, company, value.cloudSuite as cloudSuite, application
```

The aliasing of the variable derived inside the value map is the reason WITH is needed for this case (**value.cloudSuite as cloudSuite**) for all usages of the conditional procs.

Comment: Thank you @InverseFalcon, that helped. But I still have a similar problem with the next section where I tried to use these nodes for creating edges. I added the changes to the script to the main question under Edit 1.

Comment: The value map only has the values returned in the associated conditional proc. It looks like you're trying to use it across several (value.application, value.company, value.cloudsuite etc) but that doesn't work. Right after the proc call that returns cloudsuite, follow that with a WITH where you get value.cloudsuite in scope. Then for the next conditional proc that returns something else (like application), in the next WITH clause THEN you can get value.application. The value map is specific for each proc, it doesn't accumulate everything across multiple proc calls.

Comment: Ok now it is clear that the scope of the value map is limited to each procedure. So if I get each returned value and start addidng adding their values to the next WITH clause as company, cloudSuite, application, etc... would I be able to carry the values around?

Comment: Yes, exactly this.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still not getting the values being carried over for the section where the Edges are supposed to be created. I edited the original post with the updated code (Edit 2), and when I run the query, only the first Edge (company)-[r:OWNS]->(tenant) gets created, after that all gets ignored, which I am assuming is because all the gate variables are NULL. What am I still missing there please?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I was not passing the variables as parameters and return the results back from the procedure to the main query thread.